# jQuery Table Manipulation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview table in asp.net and when I update a row on the table I need some jQuery code fired that will highlight the row that was just updated.  I was thinking that I could do something along the lines of this:

```
private string getjQueryCode(string lineNumber)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function() {");
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("$('table.OptionTable tr:nth-child({0}) td').effect('highlight', {}, 3000); ", lineNumber));
    sb.AppendLine(" });");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

but that is not working.  What I need to do is send in the line number of the row that was just updated, and have the jQuery highlight that row.  Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you just highlight the row from server code, if you don't do anything else to the row client side

Comment: I do not want the row to be perm. highlighted, I want the jQuery highlight to show and then fade away...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this...
I set a public variable that would hold the gridview edit index and then sent it through:

```
    private string getjQueryCode(string lineNumber)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function() {");
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("$('table.OptionTable tr:nth-child({0}) td').effect('highlight', {}, 3000); ", lineNumber));
    sb.AppendLine(" });");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

works like a charm.